# Transpose clumps of cell on openoffice calc

Tags: function, macros, openoffice-calc

Is there a function that can help trun this :

```
A      B     C   D    E  
asa   fafa      ada sawewf
wefw   ff       rwf   fw
rww    er       rr    23
```

into this:

```
 A       B
asa     fafa 
wefw     ff
rww      er


ada    sawewf
rwf      fw
rr       23
```

in another worksheet preferably?

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. The ods posted here : http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=62453 works as per my requests